# Dell Latitude E6510

Tags: touchpad

Need help with enabling the touchpad on a Dell Latitude E6510.  When I boot it up I can't get the touchpad to work and am unable to login to windows7.  How do I activate it without a mouse?

Comment: Does it work once you log in? Why can't you use a mouse?

Comment: How do you normally log in (click on one of those icon squares, or CTRL+ALT+DEL? What version of Windows 7?

Comment: If he had to use CTRL+ALT+DEL he would probably have the ability to log into Windows, just not use the mouse once he was in.

Comment: I believe there's a BIOS option that can disable the touchpad.  I work with this model and have touchpad blocker software installed since I often brush against the touchpad while typing.  It's likely someone disabled it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have one user account Icon at the Welcome Screen, usually the user square is selected by default, press the Enter Key or Spacebar and you will be logged in. If it then asks for a password, type it and press the Enter key again.

If you have multiple account tiles/squares, then press the tab key and you will have a slight visual indication of what account is selected by the highlighting on the tile/square, once you are on the one you want, follow the above directions.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just plug in a USB mouse